# Long Time Format in PHP

Tags: php, date

I apologise for what is probably a very simple question, but I have searched the PHP Manual and Google and cannot find an example of what I need.

Basically I am looking for a way to get a date to be saved as a variable in the following format, 22nd October 2014.

This is for a basic insert query, at the moment I am using  date('d-m-y') which produces 22-10-14.

Comment: Wow, all on one page: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: -1 for lack of basic research.  This is all there right on PHP.net `date()` function page. I would also suggest that if your are doing an "insert query" you likely don't want this format anyway.  You should use a proper format to match a proper date field format in your database.  I am not aware of any database that would accept that format for such a field type.

Comment: See the format ´F´on http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php ...

Comment: If you're planning on inserting this in a database don't store it in this format. Store the date in your database's native DateTime format and format for display when you retrieve it. If you don't you'll find any sort of query on these dates much more difficult.

Comment: Thanks, no it wasn't intended to store within a database, its actually for PHPWord to insert a document creation date into a Word Template based on date created, i.e. now(), eg $template->setValue('Value2', (date('jS F Y')));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date('jS F Y')`

Check the manual for the complete list of options: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks, I have seen that page but as a novice its not something that reads very easily.

Comment: @JonathanGreen Get comfortable with reading the documentation.  There are lots of examples there in the documentation, including for use of ordinal suffix.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I needed, I am grateful.  It is frustrating when seasoned coders give -ve feedback for lack of research for something that they take for granted, yes the manual gives j and S as examples on separate rows, it doesn't say you can combine them like jS.  Sometimes it takes an idiot to ask the obvious!